# Airflow DAG for backfill

Tags: python, pipeline, airflow

I am a newbie to Apache Airflow and trying to explore things on that tool.  I am not sure how can I use the dates in SQL Queries while bringing the data with Airflow where it is quite simple in Oozie like below:

```
"SELECT * FROM Table_Name WHERE datetm BETWEEN '${DATE_START}' AND '${DATE_STOP}'"
```

But not sure what parameters available in Airflow and how can we implement the logic to backfill or dynamic dates runtime.

Comment: Take a look here: https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#macros

Comment: @tobi6 Is there any sample code you can suggest me with implementation of above query in my question. Please help me as I am unable to find any code and I have no clue how can I do that.

Comment: StackOverflow is no code production service. Search for Airflow macros and you will find plenty examples. Also click on Airflow tag here on StackOverflow. If you have a concrete example, ask again.

Comment: Sometimes you've just gotta knuckle down and commit to understanding something. There are plenty of examples of using macros inside templates for Airflow.